# Concat strings from dataframe columns in a loop (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, concatenation

Suppose I have a DataFrame "DS_df" containing strings ands numbers. The three columns "LAultimateparentcountry", "borrowerultimateparentcountry" and "tot" form a relationship.

How can I create a dictionary out of those three columns (for the entire dataset, while order matters)? I would need to access the two countries as one variable, and tot as another. I've tried the code below so far, but this merely yields me a list with separate items. For some reason, I am also not able to get .join to work, as the df is quite big (+900k rows).

```
new_list =[]

for i, row in DS_df.iterrows():
    new_list.append(row["LAultimateparentcountry"])
    new_list.append(row["borrowerultimateparentcountry"])
    new_list.append(row["tot"])
```

Preferred outcome would be a dictionary, where I could access "Germany_Switzerland": 56708 for example. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dict this way:

```
countries_map = {}

for index, row in DS_df.iterrows():
    curr_rel = f'{row["LAultimateparentcountry"]}_{row["borrowerultimateparentcountry"]}'
    countries_map[curr_rel] = row["tot"]
```

If you are not wishing to not run over existing keys values

(and use their first appearance):

```
countries_map = {}
for index, row in DS_df.iterrows():
    curr_rel = f'{row["LAultimateparentcountry"]}_{row["borrowerultimateparentcountry"]}'
    if curr_rel not in countries_map.keys():
        countries_map[curr_rel] = row["tot"]
```

Comment: Last one did the trick for me, many thanks. Any chance how I could strip this now from duplicates?

Comment: @MaximilianBach In keys there is no dups. In case you have more matches in the df it will run over the curr key in the dict with matching value.
If you mean for values, do you wish to ignore a value if it is already present in the dict?

Comment: Yes. Apologies for being unprecise, I am rather new to the sphere. It is indeed  the value I was referring to! Is it possible to cut that out/ignore it in the first place?  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MaximilianBach
You can add a cond if it is not already present in dict values.
re-edited main ans.

Comment: Thx. and If I were to only ignore the ones, where the country relationship is duplicated? As far as I see it rn, I also ignores duplicates in the "tot" column. So i.e. Albania_UAE = 1 and Albania_Spain = 1 are both ignored and not added, as the value 1 is already present for Albania_Argentina = 1. How would I go about keeping the unique relationships in the countries, whereas duplicates in the values are still allowed? Again, thank you for the patience!

Comment: @MaximilianBach
correct.
You mentioned you don't want dups in the values.

Comment: Only in the joined "LAultimateparentcountry" + "borrowerultimateparentcountry" column. Duplicates under "tot" are fine.

Comment: @MaximilianBach So you should be good to go with the origin ans.
'Only in the joined "LAultimateparentcountry" + "borrowerultimateparentcountry" column' Will always be uniq and will run over (or you want the first 'tot' of that appearance.

Answer (score 0):

When performing operations on a dataframe it's always good to think for a solution column-wise and not row-wise.

If your dataframe is having 900k+ rows then it might be a good option to apply vectorized operations on dataframe.

**Below are two solutions:**

**Using pd.Series + to_dict():**

```
pd.Series(DS_df.tot.values, index=DS_df.LAultimateparentcountry.str.cat(DS_df.borrowerultimateparentcountry, sep="_")).to_dict()
```

**Using zip() + dict():**

```
dict(zip(DS_df.LAultimateparentcountry.str.cat(DS_df.borrowerultimateparentcountry, sep="_"), DS_df.tot))
```

Test Dataframe:

```
    DS_df = DataFrame({
        'LAultimateparentcountry':['India', 'Germany', 'India'],
        'borrowerultimateparentcountry':['France', 'Ireland', 'France'],
        'tot':[56708, 87902, 91211]
    })
DS_df


LAultimateparentcountry borrowerultimateparentcountry   tot
0   India   France  56708
1   Germany Ireland 87902
2   India   France  91211
```

Output of both solutions:

```
{'India_France': 91211, 'Germany_Ireland': 87902}
```

If the formed key has duplicates then the value will be updated.

## Which solution is more performant?

**short answer -**
zip() + dict() # if the rows are approx. below 1000000
pd.Series + to_dict() # if the rows are approx. above 1000000

**Long answer - Below are the tests:**

**Test with 30 rows and 3 columns**

zip() + dict()

```
%timeit dict(zip(DS_df.LAultimateparentcountry.str.cat(DS_df.borrowerultimateparentcountry, sep="_"), DS_df.tot))

297 µs ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

pd.Series + to_dict():

```
%timeit pd.Series(DS_df.tot.values, index=DS_df.LAultimateparentcountry.str.cat(DS_df.borrowerultimateparentcountry, sep="_")).to_dict()

506 µs ± 35.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Test with 6291456 rows and 3 columns**

pd.Series + to_dict()

```
%timeit pd.Series(DS_df.tot.values, index=DS_df.LAultimateparentcountry.str.cat(DS_df.borrowerultimateparentcountry, sep="_")).to_dict()
3.92 s ± 77.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

zip + dict()

```
%timeit dict(zip(DS_df.LAultimateparentcountry.str.cat(DS_df.borrowerultimateparentcountry, sep="_"), DS_df.tot))
3.97 s ± 226 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```